# What does "a","c","f" mean in Spyder-methods (Python)

Tags: python, function, class, methods, spyder

So, I know this might not be the place where to ask, but I can simply not figure it out! When im using Spyder and say `numpy` (np) when I type `np.` a lot of options pop up - I know most of them are functions related to np, but I kinda struggling to figure out exactly what the different calls are; they all have one letter to the very left of the name, e.g "(f) all", "(a) base".

So what is the difference between (f), (a), (c) ? My first guess would be "function", "attributes", "class" but I'm not entirely sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what is the difference between (f), (a), (c) ? My first guess would be "function", "attributes", "class" but I'm not entirely sure

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is the right interpretation.